# How much is paid to a Junior and Advanced System Administrator?

Tags: untagged

trying to understand, according to SAGE levels in http://www.sage.org/pubs/8_jobs/chapter1.pdf, how much should be paid to a Level II and Level III sysadmins.

Comment: This is too localized.  Pay will vary based on experience and location and will fluctuate with market conditions (presumably).

Comment: C´mon! a good answer can still be provided even if it's not perfect. How about some ranges with the caveat that it depends on location and market conditions? Pay should not vary much with experience as people with more experience will qualify for a higher SAGE Level.

Comment: You're question is really outside the scope of what this site is designed to provide.  My suggestion would be to go to the sites that the user below mentioned or salary.com.  Those sites collate data about that stuff that we don't.  Anything we tell you would be subjective and prone to error, not to mention out of date down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the projects and company in most cases.  You can search on the following websites for the average.

http://www.payscale.com/

http://www.indeed.com/salary

http://www.glassdoor.com/Salaries/index.htm